# C# Datetimepicker : Set forecolor to Specific Date

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I am using a datetimepicker in my application. I want it to display specific dates (in this case, all Holidays of a month) with one specific color (i.e. The holidays will be shown as red or blue or any color) when the datetimepicker is clicked and its monthview (i don't know exact name of this) is prompted. Is it possible with default datetimepicker ?

Suppose there are holidays in August are all the public holidays (in this case, every fri and sat) and some specific holidays (such as 13 Aug,19 Aug etc) and I want to show them in red/blue color. This will also occur when I change the month to September (or any month).
I shall bring the holidays from database where I keep my holiday records.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It sounds like what you'd need to do is subclass the DateTimePicker control and override its paint routine to add your custom background and highlight colours to the flyout section.  Microsoft has a tutorial on [overriding the OnPaint() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cksxshce(v=vs.85).aspx) that might help here.

Answer (score 0):

A longer time ago i had to do similar solution for a busines Application.
you might wanna look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882520.aspx
i don't think i can sum it up better than this site.

Look at "Figure 8 The RedLetterDays Display". Sounds like the thing you need.

greetings

Comment: Is it possible for **datetimepicker** of windowsforms?

Comment: I'm sorry i confused it with WPF. Couldn't find any good articles and i've never done anything familiar in forms